# Use word count in Pandas dataframe to drop rows with only one word

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (data) with 2 records:

```
id    text
0001  The farmer plants grain
0002  tuna
```

I want to count the number of words in the `text` column of this dataframe and drop rows with only one word.

I know how to count the number of words:

```
count = data['text'].str.split().str.len()
```

How do I use the results to run an IF statement that will drop rows in the dataframe? Any IF statements such as...

```
if count == 1:
    print('drop')
```

...results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-118-b3fcb0218e8e>", line 32, in <module>
    if count == 1:

  File "C:\Users\taca\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 917, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have read the Pandas documentation and other SO questions around this error, but I can't seem to get the solutions to apply correctly to my issue with the IF statement.

Any advise is greatly appreciated! As I am relatively new to SO, please let me know if there's anything I can do to improve my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a mask:

```
dropped = data[~(count==1)].copy()
```

explanation:

so assuming a df such has:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['hello my name is','hey']})
```

using your count method you could check if it =1 or not, creating a boolean mask :

```
count = data['text'].str.split().str.len()
~(count==1)
Out[18]: 
0     True
1    False
Name: text, dtype: bool
```

now you can apply that mask :

```
data[~(count==1)]
Out[22]: 
               text
0  hello my name is
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain a little more? I tried printing the `dropped` and it returns an empty dataframe.

Comment: @CameronTaylor I forgot (), corrected the answer, added info

Comment: Thank you, now when I print `dropped` I see the rows drop off - I guess I'm just not sure how to actually drop the rows from the dataframe to move forward. Also, I would like to figure out a way to somehow perform if statements so as to perform different actions on rows with one word vs. rows with many. But that's not the focus of this question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just see if it has a space

```
data = data[data.text.str.contains(' ')]
data

     id                     text
0  0001  The farmer plants grain
```

Or more generally using count

```
data = data[data.text.str.count(' ') > 0]
data

     id                     text
0  0001  The farmer plants grain
```

---

**What was wrong!**

```
count = data['text'].str.split().str.len()
```

running this results in `count` being a `pandas.Series` of lengths.

```
count == 1
```

is a `pandas.Series` of truth values.  `if count == 1` makes no sense because it attempts to determine if the entire series is `True`.  And it isn't `True` or `False`.  You have to use it differently to accomplish your goals.  I've offered a way to do that.  So has @StevenG.

Comment: This still results in the same error when I try to put it in an IF statement to then drop the offending rows: `if data[data.text.str.count(' ' ) == 0]`

Answer (score 1):

Probably late to answer but it could help new viewers. 
You can easly find the indexes of the rows, that match what you want and drop them from the dataframe.

```
wantedRows = data[data['text'].str.split().str.len()==1].index 
data =  data.drop(wantedRows, axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a conditional argument for the dataframe. It would be like this:

> df = df[df['column'].str.contains(' ')]

Asuming there is a space between the words.

Comment: How would I actually drop a column from that? Using an IF statement with what you provided runs into the same error

Comment: Thats because the if is not needed. This code drops already the rows with no spaces. Just type it as I worte it and then check your dataframe again. You will see that the rows with a single word are no longer there! :)

Comment: As a small follow-up (please let me know if I need to just post a new question), how would I somehow specify a different action other than dropping? Like for rows that contain a space, print('yes'), else print('no')?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understood your question. However, if you want is to add a new column that has true or false according to the existance or non existance of spaces, you can try *df['spaces'] = df['text'].str.contains('  ')*

Comment: That would add a column to your existing dataframe, if you just want the output to say if it has or not spaces, just write: *df['text'].str.contains(' ') *